# Java Call DLL function with String param result on Access violation

Tags: java, dll

I have to do an integration with a PinPad device.

The DLL of PinPad have a method that receive a String in Param. The following code is similar that the real code.

**This is de JavaCode:**

```
  Memory memMsgAfter = new Memory(32);
  memMsgAfter.setString(0, toHexString("0000000000000000".getBytes()));
  PinpadGertecInterface.instance.PPC_StartPINEntry_DiffWK(0, 1, 3, memMsgAfter,/* other params ommited*/)
```

**This is the assignature of the method in C:**

```
PPC_FUNCTION PPC_StartPINEntry (BYTE bMode, BYTE bIndex, BYTE bKey-
Opt, BYTE *sEncWK, /* other params */);
```

The documentation of manufacturer say this:

**bKeyOpt BYTE [IN] :**
    Keying option. View remarks for proper using.

**sEncWK BYTE * [IN]**

Encypted working key. Length is dependable
on bKeyOpt (always HEX String).
bKeyOpt = 1 => sEncWK length must be 48.
bKeyOpt = 2 => sEncWK length must be 32.
bKeyOpt = 3 => sEncWK length must be 16.

The problem is that it executes and return ACCESS VIOLATION

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0114c48e, pid=5284, tid=4856
```

Comment: There is an error in your code, and you should fix it - honestly, impossible to give a better answer without an crystal ball! What is Memory, how does your JNI code look like?

Comment: This error means that the `JVM` crashed. The cause was the dll. But if it was the parameters you passed in or the code in the dll or some other reason e.g. are you using 32 bit dll with 64 bit JVM (will not work, also the oposite either) it is not know from your OP